# Using dynamic OleDb to read excel in a DataGridView and find duplicity

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, duplicates, oledb

I am trying to make a report (save an excel) of duplicate users from a previous excel file.
The problem is that I want to show the coincidence percentage of duplicate users to save an excel report, but so far I haven't had much luck.

```
      public DataView DataImport(string archivename)
        {
            string conn = string.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0}; Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0; HDR = YES; IMEX=1'", archivename);
            // Creating a connection object using the above connection string.
            OleDbConnection conector = new OleDbConnection(conn);
            // Opening connection to the database.
            conector.Open();
            OleDbCommand consult = new OleDbCommand("select * FROM [Sheet1$]", conector);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter
            {
                SelectCommand = consult
            };
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            conector.Close();
            return ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }

        public DataView Duplicatedata(string archivename)
        {
                string conn = string.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0}; Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0; HDR = YES; IMEX=1'", archivename);
                OleDbConnection conector = new OleDbConnection(conn);
                conector.Open();
                OleDbCommand consult = new OleDbCommand("select USER_CODE,NAME, COUNT(*) as DUPLICITY FROM [Sheet1$] GROUP BY USER_CODE,NAME HAVING COUNT(*)>1 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC", conector);
                //COUNT(*)>1 sends to count in the whole file all the data that is sent to call in the GROUP BY and will show those that are repeated more than 1, this value can change
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter
                {
                    SelectCommand = consult
                };
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                conector.Close();
                return ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }

       private void btn_import_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string path = "";
                OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
                {
                    Filter = "Excel | *.xls;*.xlsx;",
                    Title = "Select Archive"
                };

                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    path = openFileDialog.FileName;
                    label3.Text = path;
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = DataImport(openFileDialog.FileName);
                    btn_import.DialogResult= DialogResult.OK;
                }          
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
        }
        private void btn_duplicates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btn_import.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = Duplicatedata(label3.Text);
                    lbllname.Text = "% Duplicity";
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Import before seeing duplicate data", "ALERT");

            }
        }
}
```

If another extension rather than OleDb is welcome to be use, is not specifically strict to use only OleDb

**Update 8/23/2022**
Implementing 100*Count(*)/(Select count(*) From [SHEETx$])

[Raw Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I4TQ.png)

[Data with duplicity percentage, but the math 100*Count(*)/(Select count(*) From [SHEETx$]) is with all the data, it has to be done with the duplicity count only. any idea is welcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbLuU.png)

Comment: Can you post a sample of what the source Excel file might look like and another one of the newly generated one?

Comment: What is that you couldn't do? Other than using more than necessary code, and nonexistent methods like DatosDuplicados (typo? should be Duplicatedata?) it looks fine.

Comment: Use Group By : var results = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("Column Name"))  Change the type (int) or Column Name (or column index) as needed.  You can remove duplicates with following : var noDuplicates = results.Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

Comment: I'm sorry my code was in spanish and i didn't saw that, i just finish the translation.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the advice. But at what position in the dataset do I have to implement this code?

Comment: After you  Fill(ds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's ACE engine is a little limited when it comes to where you can code subqueries, but you *can* put one in a data field like this:

```
Select USER_CODE,NAME, COUNT(*) as DUPLICITY
    ,100*Count(*)/(Select count(*) From [SHEET3$]) AS PctOfTotal
From [SHEET3$]
GROUP BY USER_CODE,NAME
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

The only thing I added to your original query is an extra field on line 2 above.  It includes a simple subquery to total the number of records.

**Adding Complex Filtering to the Above**

To only consider the duplicates in the percentage denominator you'll need to filter them out in a Where clause with a correlated subquery.  The complexity is still in the percentage calculation:

```
,100*Count(*)/(
  Select count(*) From [SHEET3$] x
  Where 2 >= (
    Select count(*) From [SHEET3$] y
    Where y.USER_CODE=x.USER_CODE
      and y.NAME=x.NAME)
  )
) AS PctOfTotal
```

This is likely to run pretty slowly, but as long as your spreadsheet isn't huge it should be OK.

Comment: If it were anything but an ACE OLEDB connection, I would not use this technique because you run the risk of running the subquery once per code-name combination.  Even an OLEDB connection to an ACCESS data base would allow queries of queries, a much more efficient method.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Chris, the addition was good, but the math needs to be done only with the duplicate data, not the full data, any ideas to do that in the query?

Comment: A better approach would be to make your OLEDB connection through an ACCESS data base that maps your [SHEET3$] as a table, then create a querydef to count the user_code, name combinations like this: `Select user_code, name, count(*) as occurrences from [sheet3table] Group By user_code, name Having count(*) > 1`.

Comment: your complex filtering is super nice, but in the case that i need a third parameter, how can i make that relation of  y.USER_CODE=x.USER_CODE
      and y.NAME=x.NAME work with a third parameter?

Comment: When i insert your code an error appear: Query input must contain at least one table or query